# How to track Icecast2 visits with Matomo?

Tags: matomo, icecast

My beloved web radio has an `icecast2` instance and it just works. We have also a Matomo instance to track visits on our WordPress website, using only Free/Libre and open source software.

The main issue is that, since Matomo tracks visits via JavaScript, direct visits to the web-radio stream are not intercepted by Matomo as default.

**How to use Matomo to track visits to Icecast2 audio streams?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep it's possible. Here my way.

First of all, try the Matomo internal import script. Be sure to set your `--idsite=` and the correct path to your Matomo installation:

```
su www-data -s /bin/bash
python2.7 /var/www/matomo/misc/log-analytics/import_logs.py --show-progress --url=https://matomo.example.com --idsite=1 --recorders=2 --enable-http-errors --log-format-name=icecast2 --strip-query-string /var/log/icecast2/access.log
```

---

NOTE: If you see this error

```
[INFO] Error when connecting to Matomo: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

In this case, be sure to have all needed plugins activated:

- Administration > System > Plugins > **Bulk plugin**

---

So, if the script works, it should start printing something like this:

```
0 lines parsed, 0 lines recorded, 0 records/sec (avg), 0 records/sec (current)
Parsing log /var/log/icecast2/access.log...
1013 lines parsed, 200 lines recorded, 99 records/sec (avg), 200 records/sec (current)
```

If so, **immediately stop the script** to avoid to import duplicate entries before installing the definitive solution.

To stop the script use `CTRL+C`.

Now we need to run this script every time the log is rotated, before rotation.

The official documentation suggests a `crontab` but I don't recommend this solution. Instead, I suggest to configure `logrotate` instead.

Configure the file `/etc/logrotate.d/icecast2`. From:

```
/var/log/icecast2/*.log {
       ...
       weekly
       ...
}
```

To:

```
/var/log/icecast2/*.log {
        ...
        daily
        prerotate
                su www-data -s /bin/bash --command 'python2.7 ... /var/log/icecast2/access.log' > /var/log/logrotate-icecast2-matomo.log
        endscript
        ...
}
```

IMPORTANT: In the above example replace `...` with the right command.

Now you can also try it manually:

```
logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.d/icecast2
```

From another terminal you should be able to see its result in real-time with:

```
tail -f /var/log/logrotate-icecast2-matomo.log
```

If it works it means everything will work perfectly and automatically, importing all visits every day, without any duplicate and without missing any lines.

More documentation here about the import script itself:

https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo-log-analytics

More documentation here about logrotate:

https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate